# where is the sort control menu in crystal report XI release 2?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

why in the insert menu there is no sort control ? I use crystal report XI release 2. I have also been looking at other menus but not found. do you know where the sort control in crystal report XI release 2 ?

Comment: check this link https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/123302-202370144

Answer (score 0):

in the "report" menù there are "group sort expert" and "record soft expert"

Comment: i want to : when i click field heading , it will be sorting by asc , when i click again it will be sorting by desc. How to make it?